# Tests made to run pip in Windows10 not working

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

I have spent sometime trying to use `pip` but is not working. I am using Python 3.9.4. and Windows10.
From *py.exe* (command prompt from python) these are the inputs and outputs.
Input 1:

```
py -m pip install pyautogui
```

Output1:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -m pip install pyautogui
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Input2:

```
py -3.9 -m pip install pyautogui
```

Output2:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -3.9 -m pip install pyautogui
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now I change to *cmd* from windows to check if there is any pip installed adn this is what I get.
Input1:

```
py -m pip --version
```

Ouput1:

```
pip 20.2.3 from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

**So, how can I run pip?**

Comment: just pip install pyautogui doesnt work for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use `pip` from a python file or from cmd? Because if you need to do it from a python file, use

```
from os import system
system("py -3.9 -m pip install pyautogui")
```